# search data in elastic search based on some fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to EL and want to search on this data based on "`type:`": "`load`".

Please help

```
    {
   "took": 14,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1109,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {"_index": "4",
            "_type": "aa",
            "_id": "xx",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "useRange": false,
               "Blueprint": 4,
               "standardDeviation": 0,
               "occurrences": 0,
               "type:": "load",
               }...
               {
               }
```

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with field name 'type' we change the name to typemetrics and below query is working
i thing type might be acting as keyword

```
" GET /4/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term" : { "typemetrics" : "load"} 
  }
} "
```

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch Documentation will help you:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html

**EDIT**

Query is `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/sample/_search?q=type:load&pretty'`

and Output will be

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.30685282,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "sample",
      "_type" : "data",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.30685282,
      "_source" : {
        "useRange" : false,
        "Blueprint" : 4,
        "standardDeviation" : 0,
        "occurrences" : 0,
        "type" : "load"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: really appreciate if you can give exact query

Comment: when you will search type: it will give you syntax error, remove that : from type and store that record in es index and search using Query I added in answer.